# i am not able to get any response from the website while using response in python. I am gettting a time out error 10060

Tags: python, response, extract

```
import requests
import pandas


def url(index, st_symbol, exp_date):
 
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=20AUG2020', headers = headers)
```

error = ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10060, 'WSAETIMEDOUT')"))

**website** - https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=20AUG2020

Comment: The error code is pretty clear. It's timing out. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: try using selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `User-Agent` to different one I was able to get the HTML:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
}

page = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=20AUG2020', headers=headers)
print(page.text)
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

...
```

Comment: Hi just wanted to know why the user agent which i had defined did not work.

Comment: @DilipKriplani Looking at your User-Agent, the Chrome 45 is really old (2015? I think). So this is probably suspicious to the server and it blocks the script.

Answer (score 0):

`10060` seems to be an error coming from `low-latency connections.` From sources, the best fix is to either speed-up your connection by disabling any `downloads` you may be having or by adding `timeouts` to your connection(s) this can be done in many ways depending on how you're trying to access the remote hosts.

Luckily, the requests library got that ability!
Your code should look like this:

```
import requests
import pandas

def url(index, st_symbol, exp_date):
 
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?segmentLink=17&instrument=OPTIDX&symbol=NIFTY&date=20AUG2020', timeout=0.001, headers=headers) # Timeout can be any value, format: <second>.<milisecond>
```

Documentation for Error 10060: [10060 Connection Error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/191143/10060-connection-timed-out-error-with-proxy-server-or-isa-server-on-sl)

Documentation for Timeouts: [Quickstart - Requests.Timeouts](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts)

Comment: Did you try to increase the timeout?